# Xamarin.Forms Center ListView Items

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How do I center listview items within a Xamarin.Forms app?
The listview items are currently left-aligned.
I want them to be center-aligned.

I have the following code:

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scott the Grid always expands to occupy 100% of the available space. There is no way as far as I can tell to override this even explicitly setting a widthrequest on the grid doesn't even seem to help.

I assume you have a larger layout requirement your attempting to satisfy as centering first and Last name in a listView would be better accomplished with a Stacklayout instead of a grid.
IE

```
<ViewCell.View>    
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding LastName}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
</ViewCell.View>
```

But assuming you really need a Grid then I can offer only 1 addition to Tomasz's suggestion.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
<ColumnDefinition />
<ColumnDefinition/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
</Grid>
```

This create two Columns on the outside to eat up the space forcing the names to the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Without having actually tried it...

Your cell view is `<Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">`, but the Grid itself is expanded to fit the cell, so the `HorizontalOptions` there is inconsequential.

You need to put a secondary container inside that Grid that will be centered,
something like:

```
<ViewCell.View>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center"> 
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</ViewCell.View>
```

You could also try (if the above doesn't work) adding 3 columns (and 3 rows for vertical alignment) to the Grid with sizes (auto)-(*)-(auto) and putting the StackPanel in the center cell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

EDITED:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

Comment: This won't do a thing because both columns are "auto"-sized, so the first column is always the size of the FirstName label and second column takes the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Just by adding  HorizontalOptions="Center" to Label worked for me, good luck

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```